# How to plot a super ellipse

Tags: plotting, parametric-functions

I am trying to plot a super ellipse. It's like a regular ellipse but there are added terms so you can define how box like the ellipse will be and on the other extreme how concave the shape will be. I have gotten it to plot in one quadrant but not all four. Specifically I am trying to plot the definition using a sign function:
[image: x(t)=(|cos(t)|^(2/n))*a*sgn(cos(t)), y(t)=(|sin(t)|^(2/n))*a*sgn(sin(t)), and where sgn is a piecewise sign function sgn(w)=[{{-1,w<0},{0,w=0},1,w>0}}]

I am pretty new to Mathematica so I do not have a super complex script yet. I have considered using `Module` but I am not super sure how that would work. My best attempt is as follows:

```
Clear[w, t, n, a, b]
sgn[w_] := Piecewise[{{-1, w < 0}, {0, w = 0}, {1, w > 0}}];
x[t_, n_, a_] := Abs[Cos[t]]^(2/n)*a*sgn[Cos[t]];
y[t_, n_, b_] := Abs[Sin[t]]^(2/n)*b*sgn[Sin[t]];

ParametricPlot[{x[t, 4, 4], y[t, 4, 4]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

I get a couple "cannot assign to raw object" errors which I am not sure how to fix. That is why I was thinking of using `Module`. Any help would be greatly appreciated and sorry if I wasted your time with some blatantly obvious errors.

Comment: You need to use `w == 0` not `w = 0`.

Comment: Why not use the built-in function `Sign`?

Comment: This question should have not been closed. It is useful and hope it will not be deleted.

Answer (score 6):

The superellipse fullfills the equation `(x/a)^n + (y/b)^n == 1` which might be plotted simple directly using `ContourPlot`

```
With[{n = 4, a = 4, b = 4}, 
ContourPlot[(x/a)^n + (y/b)^n == 1, {x, -a, a}, {y, -b, b}]]
```

[image]

Comment: I like how simple this way is too. Both of these are really helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You can also use [`Norm`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Norm.html) with `ContourPlot` or with `RegionPlot`:

```
cp = With[{n = 4, a = 4, b = 4}, 
  ContourPlot[Norm[{x/a, y/b}, n] == 1, {x, -a, a}, {y, -b, b},
    ContourStyle -> Directive[Red, Thick]]]
```

[image]

```
rp = With[{n = 4, a = 4, b = 4}, 
  RegionPlot[Norm[{x/a, y/b}, n] <= 1, {x, -a, a}, {y, -b, b}]]
```

[image]

```
Show[rp, cp]
```

[image]

After fixing the typo mentioned by @Carl and adding the option `Exclusions->None` in OP's code:

```
Show[rp, 
 ParametricPlot[{x[t, 4, 4], y[t, 4, 4]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, 
   PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, Thick], Exclusions -> None]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this was super helpful!

Answer (score 3):

`Sign[]` is a built-in function, so:

```
With[{a = 4, b = 4, n = 4}, 
     ParametricPlot[{a Sign[Cos[t]] Abs[Cos[t]]^(2/n), b Sign[Sin[t]] Abs[Sin[t]]^(2/n)},
                    {t, 0, 2 π}, Exclusions -> None]]
```

[image: superellipse]

The `Exclusions -> None` setting is necessary here because *Mathematica* tries to be too smart in this case, and adds a needless discontinuity.